# NestedScrollView+RecyclerView Slow loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have to tell the first thing is there are too many questions similar to this question. So please before mark it as duplicate analyze once.

I have an Nested Scroll View inside of that two Recycler View are placed. First one is for horizontal scroll. Second one is for vertical scroll.

The functionalities are working fine.  Now the problem is for the first time loading takes 20seconds. ANR service called because of this. Once loaded the scrolling is also perfect.

```
RestarantListAdapter restarantListAdapter = new RestarantListAdapter(activity, restaurants_1);
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
                    binding.rvRestaurants.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager1);
                    binding.rvRestaurants.setAdapter(restarantListAdapter);
```

`binding.rvRestaurants.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

and

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(binding.rvRestaurants, false);
```

I tried above code. Is there any other possibilities for handling the first time loading issue.

Comment: Are you setring the adapter after the data is obtained? Set the adapter as soon as you can and then add the data. Aslo try with adding the 10 firsr elements and then update the adapter with the rest.

Comment: Don't use NestedScrollView, use multiple view types (getItemViewType)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Not only recycler also have some other views too.

Comment: @cutiko Can you share any example?

Comment: Your other views can be part of the RecyclerView using different item types.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I removed the Nestedscrollview and add one recyclerview Still loading taking muck time. Still ANR service called any alternatives? My data is too large I know that is causing the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

When you are using RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView then all of your items are drawn immediately (you can check how many times onBindViewHolder is called). So you basically lost all of the improvement of performance given by RecyclerView and got something like ListView. So in case you don't really have to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, don't do it.

Comment: Need Recyclerview inside nestedscrollview for sure. How to handle this.

Comment: If there are just those two RecyclerViews inside NestedScrollView, I would try to put the horizontal one inside vertical one as a row (different viewType) and remove this NestedScrollView. This should improve performance significantly

Comment: No I have some other views too.

Comment: So the only possibility that I see is paging. Don't load all the data at once

Comment: ListView also recycles views. The API just isn't as nice and extensible.